# Exception Handling with subprocess.run in Python

Tags: python, shell, exception, subprocess, popen

I am trying to create a function that can run any shell command and return the stdout of that command, without worrying about any exceptions that could be thrown. When testing the code written below with incorrect commands like `xyz testing`, I get a `FileNotFoundError` rather that the `CalledProcessError` even though the command `xyz testing` returns a non-zero return code when I ran it in the shell. But, when I run the same function with a similar invalid command like `ls -xyz` I get a `CalledProcessError` as expected. Does anyone know why the exception is not being thrown in a consistent manner.

```
    try:
        cmd_result = subprocess.run(
            cmd,
            capture_output=True,
            text=True,
            check=True,
        )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
        click.echo(exc.stderr)
        click.echo(cmd)
        sys.exit(1)
```

Thank you

I tried putting the `shell=True` option, and then the error situation swaps (`xyz testing`) passes and `ls -xyz` fails.
I have been stuck on what else I can try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are happening. With `check=True`, subprocess raises `CalledProcessError` if the command is executed and returns a non-zero exit status. When `shell=False`, the file to execute couldn't be found, so you got the `FileNotFound` error code. The program wasn't run, there was no exit code to examine, so `CalledProcessError` was not an option.

When `shell=True`, subprocess runs an intermediate shell. Now its the shell return code that matters and that can be different than the called process. Subprocess found the intermediate shell, so there is no `FileNotFound` error, but couldn't find the program so returned a non-zero value, generating the other exception. Consider the command `"xyz testing;exit 0"` this would not generate a called process error even though xyz does not exist. That's because the shell returned a 0 exit code.

Comment: How come `ls -xyz` does not raise a CalledProcessError when I use `shell=True`?

Comment: Also what would be the best way to capture the exception, without using the `shell=True`, because from what I have read, using `shell=true` can lead to a shell injection attack

Comment: @RavivermaChamarti - `subprocess.run("ls -xyz", shell=True, check=True)` should raise called process error.

Comment: To avoid a shell injection attack, skip the shell completely and use a list of the exact command to run `subprocess.run(["ls", "-xyz"], check=True)`. You can be either a file not found or called process error. If you get the entire command from the user instead of just some of its parameters, you are still vulnerable.